# Software packages won't download because of "insserv" and "virtualbox"

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

## Problem

All of the packages I try to install won't because of a problem with "insserv" and virtualbox. It's probably because of VirtualBox, but I don't know what part of it is causing the error. I'd like to know what part (or if I'm wrong whatever in Ubuntu) is causing the problem and how to fix it.

### Info

I don't know if any of the hardware info matters, but it might.

#### Software + OS

I have VirtualBox 5.1 and the extension pack installed on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04 LTS). If it matters, I have Win XP Pro with Guest Additions installed, FreeDOS, and Puppy Linux (Racy) installed, all in `~/VirtualBox VMs/`.

If it also matters, with the above VBox setup I was trying to get VMs for Fedora, Debian, OpenBSD, openSUSE, Kali, and Linux Mint. (there might be more but I can't remember)

Previously I had VBox 4.3 installed, but uninstalled it for 5.1. Earlier than that, I had Ubuntu Trusty (14.04.4 LTS) with VBox 4.3. Both only had Win XP Pro, no guest additions.

#### Hardware

Dell Precision M6300 (yes, I am old) with a NVIDIA G84GLM (Quadro FX 1600M) card, a Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini Card), and an unknown one with a driver for "Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs".

### Latest Encounter

An error when trying to install BleachBit (about 10 minutes ago):

```
installArchives() failed: Selecting previously unselected package menu.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 224061 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../menu_2.1.47ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package bleachbit.
Preparing to unpack .../bleachbit_1.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking bleachbit (1.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-notify.
Preparing to unpack .../python-notify_0.1.1-4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking python-notify (0.1.1-4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160415-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up virtualbox (5.0.18-dfsg-2build1) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.18-dfsg-2build1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-notify (0.1.1-4) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
Setting up bleachbit (1.10-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox
 virtualbox-qt
Setting up virtualbox (5.0.18-dfsg-2build1) ...
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.0.18-dfsg-2build1); however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-4.3 which provides virtualbox is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

This problem has persisted for everything I don't get off the software center or the install DVD (which I only used to get the Broadcom driver).

### `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` script

Here is an excerpt from near the beginning:

```
# Provides:       vboxdrv
# Required-Start: $syslog
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
#### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$PATH
DEVICE=/dev/vboxdrv
LOG="/var/log/vbox-install.log"
VERSION=4.3.38
MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe
```

Answer (score 0):

The log indicates that BleachBit installed successfully here:

```
Setting up bleachbit (1.10-1) ...
```

Dpkg is trying to tell you that the virtualbox package installed, but didn't get through the configure phase completely. Probably the postinst script for virtualbox in /var/lib/dpkg/info. The main failure is here:

```
insserv: script virtualbox: service vboxdrv already provided!
```

So the script it trying to register vboxdrv to start at boot by looking at the /etc/init.d scripts. I'm guessing something went wrong during an upgrade and left some files behind.

You can look at a resource like this https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot and try to debug further. I'm betting there is more than one script in /etc/init.d which contains the "Provides: vboxdrv" header. You could grep for that in /etc/init.d and figure out which one is the old one.

You could also try purging the virtualbox package and reinstalling it.

Comment: Ok, i'll try that.

Comment: I have provided the vboxdrv script above.

Comment: Do any of the other scripts in /etc/init.d provide vboxdrv? Try `grep vboxdrv /etc/init.d/* | grep Provides` and see if there is more than one match.